# GNU make preprequisite execution order

Tags: gnu-make

Say I have the following GNU make targets:

```
    create_dir: 
        @mkdir objects

    build_asm: $(ASM_FILES)
        @echo building assembly files...

    build_c: $(C_FILES)
        @echo building c files...
```

I have a generic rule for creation of object files from .asm or .c files. I want to combine these into a single target as follows...

```
all: create_dir build_asm build_c
    @echo build complete
```

...and I want to build this target using the jobs using multiple jobs to increase performance. The *.c and *.s files should be placed in the directory created by **build_c**, so allowing make to execute them in any order is problematic.

Is there a way to force make to resolve the phony target **create_dir** before resolving **build_c** and **build_asm** without breaking up the target?

Answer (score 3):

Creating an objects directory is a typical use case of "order-only-prerequisites" (see [Types of Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) in the GNU make manual):

```
create_dir: 
    @mkdir objects

build_asm: $(ASM_FILES) | create_dir
    @echo building assembly files...

build_c: $(C_FILES) | create_dir
    @echo building c files...

all: build_asm build_c
    @echo build complete
```